# MemoryError: Unable to allocate 115. GiB for an array with shape (1122, 1122, 12288) and data type float64

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, feature-extraction, orb

I am trying to pass a function that returns a flattened array of images and labels and my OS is windows 10. Moreover, when i try calling the function i the error described in the title

```
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 115. GiB for an array with shape (1122, 1122, 12288) and data type float64
```

What i want to do is: i want to extract features from a dataset with keypoints on them, inside a function and use train_test_split for my dataset, but even if i try to flatten the images with keypoints, it'll get me the error, the only way to flatten are the same images without keypoints.

Here's how i was trying:

```
def load_image_files(fullpath, dimension=(35, 35)):
    flat_data = []
    orb = cv2.ORB_create(edgeThreshold=1, nfeatures=22)
    key_points = [cv2.KeyPoint(64, 9, 10), 
    cv2.KeyPoint(107, 6, 10), 
    cv2.KeyPoint(171, 10, 10)]
    kp, des = orb.compute(imageList, key_points)
    kparray = cv2.drawKeypoints(imageList, kp, None, flags=cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS); 
    img_resized = resize(kparray, dimension, anti_aliasing=True, mode='reflect')
    img_resized = img_resized.flatten()
    flat_data.append(img_resized)
    images.append(flat_data)

        flat_data = np.array(flat_data)
        images = np.array(images)
        return Bunch(data=flat_data,
                     images=images)
```

Comment: usually you write batch generators for this, so only a small portion of the dataset is loaded in memory at once. What do you use to train the model?

Comment: Im using train_test_split and OneVsRest for multiclass classification. How can i write small batches though?

Comment: Im not using neural networks, though.

Comment: This applies to any algorithm using SGD, including logistic regression. What I meant by this question is what framework you're using (sklearn, tf, statmodels)?

Comment: Sorry, i'm using sklearn

Comment: unfortunately, it looks like sklearn doesn't provide suitable interface for this. You might have better luck with tensorflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here in your function.You are appending all of your flatten images to a single list which is causing this memory error.Instead you can use dask arrays to store them.The dask array uses the hard disk to store the data which is very large to fit in memory.Dask is a python library similar to sparks which has been designed for big data.

Comment: Tried using Dask arrays like this:     flat_data = da.from_array(flat_data, chunks=(200, 361 ))
    target = da.from_array(target, chunks=(200, 361))
    images = da.from_array(images, chunks=(200, 361)) and got this error: ValueError: Chunks do not add up to shape. Got chunks=((200, 361),), shape=(1122,)

Comment: It's because the broken chunks should be each of equal sizes.The simplest solution could be make the no of samples such that they can be broken down into a chunk of 200 in your case.Say if you have 10402 then drop 2 samples so that no of samples left can exactly be divided into part of 200 each

Comment: Also another solution could be storing your data as numpy arrays of some chunks.Say in your example if you are generating 10000 samples.Then instead of appending it to a list.You can append 500 samples which could fit in your memory.Then you can dump that array as pickle dump or using np.save fun then you clear your appended list.Again append next 500 samples and save as numpy arrays.While training you can write a generator which will load those arrays one by one and will train your model.